# CakePHP HABTM: how to find all Photos HABTM multiple Tags?

Tags: cakephp, find, join, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have two tables, photos and tags, with a standard photos_tags link table.

My models show Photos HABTM Tags, and I can update both fine with the links updating too.

My question is: say I now want to find all Photos tagged with *both* "Sunset" and "Ocean" - how do I go about that?

I've tried doing an inner join as per [Nate's Bakery post](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/view/quick-tip-doing-ad-hoc-joins-in-model-find) and I can now find all photos tagged with either OR both, but I want just those with both tags (e.g. an "AND" find, if that's the correct phrase). Currently adding more tags gives me more results - I want less results as more tags are added!

Alternatively, if there isn't a nice Cakey way, how would you do it? Multiple searches and then compare the arrays? Seems kinda wasteful though...

TIA.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind condition arrays like this

```
'conditions' => array('AND' => array('field' => 'value', 'field' => 'value'))
```

Comment: How would this work on HABTM? I'm not looking at two fields as such, but a pair of relationships.

Comment: I've had trouble citing two identical keys in a conditions array.  I've had to wrap each in its own array to fix it. Like this...

'conditions' => array( 'and' => array( array('field'=>'value'), array('field'=>'value2') )